# Better understanding the dispatcher's effect on runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dispatcher

The situation I'm trying to understand is as follows;

1. There is a algorithm that passes through a lot of different methods and objects. Some of these methods call the dispatcher to update various UI elements.
2. excecution time is important, I'm optimizing with the goal of shaving even miliseconds off.
3. For some reason, even if it's threaded and dispatched with BeginInvoke and ApplicationIdle priority, the UI code seems to be slowing down my overall execution time. The only way I've found to improve the runtime is to dispatch that first initial method call that branches out into the different code paths.

There's a little too much code to post here. The basic phenomenon I'm trying to better understand is why my code executes faster on the UI thread?

My only thought is that by dispatching everything, the low priority dispatches are properly queued behind the rest of the executing code. Is this correct? And if so am I doing something wrong? Feels wrong to optamize by running everything on the UI  thread.

Comment: Lacking a good [mcve], your question is especially too broad. That said, thread context switches are always going to cost performance, and this is doubly so when data has to be marshaled between threads, as when using the "invoking" paradigm. You should try to minimize the number of UI updates...generally, background threads tend to update view model values far too often, leading to extra UI overhead that doesn't benefit the user anyway (it's not like they can keep up with the amount of processing a background thread can do).

Comment: _One_ possible approach: use an intermediary view model object, not bound to the UI, to take updates from the background thread. On a timer (once a second, for example), copy values from that object to the actual view model object. Alternatively, just have the background thread keep computational progress in whatever data structure or local variables are convenient for it, and only update the actual view model object every one second. Etc.